# how to know the stat date and end date of transaction in oracle

Tags: oracle

I Have An Table :

```
Ename Deptno JoinDate
RAKESH 10     01-OCT-90
RAKESH 20     01-DEC-91
RAKESH 30     01-MAR-92
```

In This Query A particular Employee has join Join Different Deptno in a organization i need to know the his terminated date with days in between there join date from 10 to till 30 department

O/p:

```
Ename     Deptno    StartDate     Enddate        Working Days
RAKESH   10      01-OCT-90     30-NOV-91        425
RAKESH   20      01-DEC-91     29-Feb-92        90
RAKESH   30      01-MAR-92     Still Working    9317
```

Comment: Well what have you attempted?

Answer (score 2):

There you go

```
-- just sample of data from your question
with t1(Ename, Deptno, JoinDate) as(
  select 'RAKESH', 10, to_date('01-OCT-90', 'dd-mon-rr') from dual union all
  select 'RAKESH', 20, to_date('01-DEC-91', 'dd-mon-rr') from dual union all
  select 'RAKESH', 30, to_date('01-MAR-92', 'dd-mon-rr') from dual
)
-- actual query
select ename
     , deptno
     , to_char(joindate, 'dd-mon-rr') as startdate
     , nvl(to_char(jdate - 1, 'dd-mon-rr'), 'Still Working...') as enddate
     , (nvl(jdate - 1, sysdate) - joindate) as working_days
  from (
        select ename
             , deptno
             , joindate
             , lead(joindate, 1) over(partition by ename 
                                      order by joindate) as jdate
         from t1 q )
```

Result:

```
 ENAME      DEPTNO STARTDATE          ENDDATE            WORKING_DAYS
------ ---------- ------------------ ------------------ ------------
RAKESH         10 01-oct-90          30-nov-91                   425
RAKESH         20 01-dec-91          29-feb-92                    90
RAKESH         30 01-mar-92          Still Working...     9343.50605

3 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need a subquery. 2 separate `Lead` functions will give you the output. And assuming that your date column is actually `date` datatype, not string. Else you have to use `to_date` convert it to `date`.

Also, showing 'Still Working' in a date column is not suggestible. If it is for reporting purpose, then displaying `EndDate` as `NULL` will solve your purpose. But in any case if you want to do it, then use `to_char` function to convert `EndDate` to char and then use `NVL` as shown by Nicholas.

```
select ename,deptno,JoinDate,
    lead(JoinDate,1) over(partition by ename order by joindate) - 1
    as enddate
    ,FLOOR(
            nvl(lead(JoinDate,1) over(partition by ename order by joindate) 
            ,sysdate
                ) 
            - joindate 
          )
    as WorkingDays
from tbl;
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=81dc2dce4cbf2b90543a38b33335abe2)

Output

```
ENAME   DEPTNO  JOINDATE    ENDDATE     WORKINGDAYS
RAKESH  10      01-OCT-90   30-NOV-91   426
RAKESH  20      01-DEC-91   29-FEB-92   91
RAKESH  30      01-MAR-92   null        9343
```

Explanation: `LEAD` will give you next row result (defined by partition by and order by). You can use it to use next date in current row for `end_date`. And you can subtract `EndDate` and `JoinDate` to get the output.